# Is this voice change correct?

Tags: passive-voice

I have written a text about a motorbike. I would like to rewrite it converting into passive voice. I know how to do it grammatically. But I'm not sure the change I have made sounds right or not.

> A few days ago, somebody stole Keith Dunn's motorbike. Keith had left
>   his motorbike outside his house. Keith reported the theft to the
>   police. **The police told him they would try to find his motorbike**. This
>   morning, the police called Keith and asked him to go to the police
>   station. They had found his motorbike. The thieves had painted it and
>   then sold it to someone else. The new owner had parked the motorbike
>   outside the police station. The police arrested the thieves.

And after voice change I rewrote the text as:

> Keith Dunn's motorbike was stolen a few days ago. His motorbike had
>   been left outside his house. The theft was reported to the police. **He
>   was told a police would try to find his motorbike**. This morning, Keith
>   was called and asked to go to the police station. His motorbike had
>   been found. It had been painted by the thieves and then had been sold
>   to someone else. The motorbike had been parked by the new owner
>   outside the police station. The thieves were arrested by the police.

Comment: *Police* is plural and has no singular form.  We usually say *the police*, never **a police*.

Comment: [Wikipedia has an entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) on words with no singular form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the following:

> He was told by police that they would try to find his motorbike.
>
> He was told that the police would try to find his motorbike.

*Police* is treated as plural and usually "*the police*" but never "***a** police*". If you were to refer to an individual *police officer*, then it would become an adjective to the noun officer, man or woman e.g.. a police officer; a policeman; a policewoman.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL and thanks for your answer! Can you add some more information about why this is correct?